# Proof of Boundary of $\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2: x > 0, y =\sin(1/x)\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let set $X =\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2: x > 0, y = \sin(1/x)\}$ and set $Y = X \cup \{(0,y): y \in [-1,1]\}$. This question follows from a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234195/is-the-set-defined-by-y-sin1-x-open-or-closed)  about set $X$. According to Harambe's answer for that post, to show that $Y = \partial X$, we need to show that $Y$ is closed.

I attempted to show this by considering $Y^c$ is open by finding open balls about each point in $Y^c$ that do not intersect $Y$. For points $\vec{x_0} = (x_0, y_0) \not \in Y$ such that:

- $x_0 < 0$, any ball $B_{-x_0}(\vec{x_0})$ does not contain any points in set $Y$.
- $x_0 \geq 0$ and $y > 1$, ball $B_{\lvert y-1 \rvert}(\vec{x_0})$ also does not contain any points in set $Y$.
  For $x_0 \geq 0$ and $y < -1$, ball $B_{\lvert y+1 \rvert}(\vec{x_0})$ also does not contain any points in set $Y$.

I am having difficulty finding balls that do not contain points in $Y$ around $(x_0,y_0) \in \{(x,y): x > 0, y \in [-1,1] \}$.

Also, is there an easier way to show that set $Y$ is closed?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In the second bullet item, the ball for $y<-1$ is $B_{\lvert y+1 \rvert}(\vec{x_0})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the third bullet item you consider, let us define the curve $C_a$ as the image of $f:[a,\infty)\to\Bbb R$, $f(x)=\sin(\tfrac1x)$.

Given $P(x_0, y_0)\notin X$, $x_0>0,$ let $d_P=d(P,C_{\frac{x_0}2})$ be the distance of $P$ to $C_{\frac{x_0}2}$ which is well-defined and non-zero since $C_{\frac{x_0}2}$ is closed set. Let $r_P=\min\{d_P,\frac{x_0}2\}$. Then
$$B_{r_P}(\vec P)\cap Y=\emptyset.$$

Comment: Thank you for your help! Could you help me understand why you chose $x_0/2$ for $C_{x_0/2}$ and for $min\{d_P, x_0/2\}$?

Comment: Also, since $d(P,C_{x_0/2})$ is defined as $\inf\{(P,z): z \in C_{x_0/2}\}$, how do we know that the infimum value is not zero?

Comment: @monkeyking Because I cut $X$ at $x=x_0/2$. For the second question,  then $P$ would be in the closure.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to prove $Y$ is closed, in my opinion, is to use the definition that the closure of a set is the union of the set and its limit points.  Since the closure of a set is closed, and $Y$ is the closure of $X$, then $Y$ is closed.